# Is really TCP takes 3*RTT time to make a connection?

Tags: tcp, networking, transport-protocol, layer4

TCP takes 3 RTT time I have read from [one stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636841/nonpersistent-http-1-1-connections-faster-than-persistent-one) to make a connection with server. We  know that TCP takes triple (Syn, Syn/Ack, Ack) to make a connection by 3-way handshake with server. But 3 RTT don't understand this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The triple handshake take three *single* trips between the connection partners A and B:

1. A->B: SYN
2. B->A: SYN+ACK [A is fully synchronized after receiving B's SYN/ACK]
3. A->B: ACK [A can already send data through the socket right after ACKing B's sequence number]

A *round* trip is both ways: A->B->A.

Assuming A->B and B->A delays are equal, the triple handshake takes exactly 1.5 RTT.

Comment: why the answer is saying 3Rtt?

Comment: @AlokMaity You'll need to ask the author...